# tracking sign-ups with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

our marketing consultant has asked me to help with configuring google analytics to setup Goal Tracking for User Signups... from what I've read this is accomplished by assigning the URL of the page the user is directed to after a successful signup to the Goal you are trying to track.

but what if the URL your user is directed to is a URL they regularly visit? e.g. after signing up they are directed to their profile page - which is the same page they visit every time they login. is there some way to configure a referer to go with the goal URL so that it is the pair of them that define the goal? e.g. user visits /profile and is referred by /signup.

further complication: what if after signup the user is directed to a different page depending on the user type? it would be nice to configure a single Goal with multiple URLs (but still using the referer restriction described above).

an alternative would be to use an event... if the server creates a user then it could signal the view to output the javascript code that generates the appropriate event.

or... is there a way for server-side code to send events to google analytics? is there an api?

Answer (score 1):

If your users are directed to is a URL they regularly visit you can make a conditional statement for the goal occasion with a virtual pageview, have a look at this: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/et_vps/index.html

If after signup the user is directed to a different page depending on the user type, you can use regular expressions to set goal URL pattern, like this ^user./login./(type1|type2|type3)/$, look here for more info: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/regex_ga/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question in google and believe I found a more appropriate answer.

Google Analytics now provide a service called [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).
This will allow you to send server-side requests to track your users activities in your analytics account.

To track a sign up event as mentioned in the question, the best way I can see would be to first create an event based goal in your account with the category set to 'users' and an action as 'sign_up' (you can optionally provide a label and value). Then in your code once a successful sign-up occurs (maybe when a user confirms their activation email link?), send a POST request to www.google-analytics.com/collect with the following payload:

```
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=event         // Event hit type
&ec=user         // Event Category. Required.
&ea=sign_up      // Event Action. Required.
&el=label        // Event label.
&ev=1            // Event value.
```

A full list of the parameters and their meanings are defined here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event that is triggered when the user submits the sign-up form :

```
onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category','Action','Label','Value']);"
```

and use the Category / Action / Label [data model](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) in Google Analytics to pass whatever data you need to pass, for example :

```
onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Sign-up','Premium','6-month',6]);"
```

You then have to configure this Goal in Google Analytics as an Event, which lets you choose which combination of each of the fields Category / Action / Label / Value you want to use.

Another option, maybe less maintenance-heavy, is to use a query-string to identify people that get back to the Profile page after having just signed up. So instead of sending them back to /user/profile after they sign up, you send them back to /user/profile/?sign-up=true.

You will then be able to track these pages as a URL goal in GA using a Regular expression like :

```
\?sign-up=true
```

Comment: i thought about the "on submit" event except that doesn't take into account failed signup attempts (the form is submitted in either case but the account is only created if there are no errors). your second suggestion however might work...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper function for tracking GA events.

```
function trackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(category, action, label) {
   try {
     ga('send', 'event', category, action, label);
   } catch (e) {
      console.warn('Google analytics error: ' + e);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
trackGoogleAnalyticsEvent('Signup', 'Signup Success', 'Facebook');
```